# Mocking of GPS not updating lon and lat

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Ok I am using  [Lockito](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=en_GB)  from the app store andriod to mock my location and I am getting the first long and lat but its not updating as it should I am storing the location in a list

This function here locationObtained  does not appear to be getting called more than once.

I am using a real device for testing and have granted pemission to location.

```
private async Task<int> StartGps()
{ 

        var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");                     
            }
            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
            status = results[Permission.Location];
        }

            ILocation loc = DependencyService.Get<ILocation>();
            loc.locationObtained += (object ss, ILocationEventArgs ee) =>
            {
                lat = ee.lat;
                lng = ee.lng;

                lbllat.Text = ee.lat.ToString();
                lbllong.Text = ee.lng.ToString();
                Position position = new Position(lat, lng);


                postionsList.Add(position);
            };
        listPostions.ItemsSource = postionsList;
        loc.ObtainMyLocation();

       return 1;
}
```

In My Listview I have the following.

```
<ListView x:Name="listPostions" > 
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
         Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

     <Label Text="{Binding Latitude}"
                            TextColor="#f35e20" />
     <Label Text="{Binding Longitude}"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            TextColor="#503026" />
                            </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The problem is its not auto updating my app i have seti lockito to be the choosen app in developer options I have location on and can see the movement in Lockito fine but i cant see the orther cordinates from Lockito comming into my app.

This is my andriod function

```
public class GetMyLocation : Java.Lang.Object, ILocation, ILocationListener
{
    public event EventHandler<ILocationEventArgs> locationObtained;

    public void ObtainMyLocation()
    {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
        lm.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider,0, 0, this);

    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            LocationEventArgs args = new LocationEventArgs();
            args.lat = location.Latitude;
            args.lng = location.Longitude;
            locationObtained(this, args);
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because Lockito is not actually updating your location?

Comment: @PatrickGoode it is cause other apps are doing it